# Equivalent of jQuery .hide() to set visibility: hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, visibility

In jQuery, there are `.hide()` and `.show()` methods which sets the CSS `display: none` setting.

Is there an equivalent function which would set the `visibility: hidden` setting?

I know I can use `.css()` but I prefer some function like `.hide()` or so. Thanks.

Comment: You can implement your own based on `.toggle()`

Comment: I'm also a fan of jQuery's toggleClass() method for this :) http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/  Feel free to check out the example I shared in my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/14632687/1056713

Answer (score 475, accepted):

You could make your own plugins.

```
jQuery.fn.visible = function() {
    return this.css('visibility', 'visible');
};

jQuery.fn.invisible = function() {
    return this.css('visibility', 'hidden');
};

jQuery.fn.visibilityToggle = function() {
    return this.css('visibility', function(i, visibility) {
        return (visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    });
};
```

If you want to overload the original jQuery `toggle()`, which I don't recommend...

```
!(function($) {
    var toggle = $.fn.toggle;
    $.fn.toggle = function() {
        var args = $.makeArray(arguments),
            lastArg = args.pop();

        if (lastArg == 'visibility') {
            return this.visibilityToggle();
        }

        return toggle.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxTeU/).

Comment: @Tomas You'd have to shadow `toggle()` which could break other scripts. If you wanted, you could add an extra argument to `toggle()` to specify whether `visibility` or `display` should be toggled. I'd just use the custom one in my last example, however. :)

Comment: Could you post an example on how to support additional parameters of `show` (speed, easing, callback)?

Comment: @thg435 I provided an example of overloading an existing jQuery method. You should be able to adapt the example to what you desire.

Comment: Sorry alex, I misunderstood what `.toogle()` is ... So my first comment here is bogus. The first solution is the one to go.

Comment: Just a note - `!` is not necessary if you're using parens. `!function(){}()` or `(function(){})()` make for a function expression, using both is superfluous.

Comment: It's superflous if you look at it that way, but there is a purpose. If  this is concatenated to another script with a `(function() { })()` or similar, ASI won't kick in because it looks like a function invocation. Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AT8xn/), then remove the `!`.

Comment: @NoBugs Automatic Semi-colon Insertion. I wrote a [blog post](http://blog.alexanderdickson.com/javascript-semicolons) about it here.

Comment: The first block lacks a bunch of semicolons, please add them. It does work this way, but is considered bad style.

Comment: @poitroae Sure, but remember you're free to edit the answer. I'd say it's bad practice to mix styles, which I did.

Comment: this works well when working with google maps, the panel that gmaps loads into has to be visible so it can work out the width/height etc.  if your panel is initially set to display:none, the map will not display correctly. setting visibility:hidden though will work and the funcs above allow me to easily manage the visible state with jquery. thank you!

Comment: override not over load ;)

Comment: @VishalSakaria It's not really a well-defined term as far as I know, so it should be okay to use it here.

Comment: jQuery actually has a built in toggleClass() method for this :) http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/   Feel free to check out the example I shared in my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14632687/1056713

Comment: @ChayaCooper This isn't toggling classes, but toggling visibility.

Answer (score 120):

There isn't one built in but you could write your own quite easily:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.invisible = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
        });
    };
    $.fn.visible = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).css("visibility", "visible");
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

You can then call this like so:

```
$("#someElem").invisible();
$("#someOther").visible();
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/nGhjQ/).

Comment: Good point, just a force of habit. Thanks. +1 to alex's answer!

Comment: Just curious, what's the point in wrapping these two functions in the `(function($) {...}(jQuery));` wrapper? I've never defined my own functions in jQuery before, I have always just defined functions in straight JavaScript.

Comment: @VoidKing - It's just the "best practice" for jQuery plugins as per the docs. It allows you to use the `$` identifier inside the function, even if it refers to something else in the parent scope.

Comment: jQuery actually has a built in toggleClass() method for this :) http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/  Feel free to check out the example I shared in my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/14632687/1056713

Answer (score 61):

An even simpler way to do this is to use jQuery's [toggleClass()](http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/) method

CSS

```
.newClass{visibility: hidden}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class=trigger>Trigger Element </a>
<div class="hidden_element">Some Content</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
        $(".hidden_element").toggleClass("newClass");
    });
});
```

Comment: I like this approach. It's less self-contained because it requires separate stylesheet, but it helps keep all style information in the stylesheets which is where it should belong. If you wanted to disable the visibility you could change a css tag in one place instead of changing all your js code.

Comment: For those using bootstrap, this class is called invisible.

Answer (score 27):

If you only need the standard functionality of hide only with visibility:hidden to keep the current layout you can use the callback function of hide to alter the css in the tag. [Hide docs in jquery](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

An example :

```
$('#subs_selection_box').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $(this).css({"visibility":"hidden"});
      $(this).css({"display":"block"});
});
```

This will use the normal cool animation to hide the div, but after the animation finish you set the visibility to hidden and display to block.

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/bTkKG/1/

I know you didnt want the $("#aa").css() solution, but you did not specify if it was because using only the css() method you lose the animation.

Answer (score 3):

**Pure JS** equivalent for jQuery hide()/show() :

```
function hide(el) {
    el.style.visibility = 'hidden';    
    return el;
}

function show(el) {
    el.style.visibility = 'visible';    
    return el;
}

hide(document.querySelector(".test"));
// hide($('.test')[0])   // usage with jQuery
```

We use `return el` due to satisfy [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#JavaScript) "desing pattern".

Here is [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/1ngc5pdz/19/).

---

Below I also provide **[HIGHLY unrecommended](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/)** alternative, which is however probably more "close to question" answer:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.hide = function() {
    this.style.visibility = 'hidden';  
    return this;
}

HTMLElement.prototype.show = function() {
    this.style.visibility = 'visible';  
    return this;
}

document.querySelector(".test1").hide();
// $('.test1')[0].hide();   // usage with jQuery
```

of course this not implement jQuery 'each' (given in **@JamesAllardice** answer) because we use pure js here.

Working example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ce78fz9v/11/).

Answer (score 3):

Here's one implementation, what works like `$.prop(name[,value])` or `$.attr(name[,value])` function. If `b` variable is filled, visibility is set according to that, and `this` is returned (allowing to continue with other properties), otherwise it returns visibility value.

```
jQuery.fn.visible = function (b) {
    if(b === undefined)
        return this.css('visibility')=="visible";
    else {
        this.css('visibility', b? 'visible' : 'hidden');
        return this;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
$("#result").visible(true).on('click',someFunction);
if($("#result").visible())
    do_something;
```