# Change Toggle(); from Display:none to Visibility:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, visibility

This code is working successfully on the project that I am working on.  The problem with this is that the elements that this code affects are positioned absolutely.  When .field-name-field-pin-point it clicked the element .group dealer is hidden, but the .field-name-field-pin-point moves off of the page.  Ideally, I would like the visibility to be set at none upon page load, but it would probably be easier to do that part in CSS.  Here is what I am currently using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.node-202 .field-name-field-pin-point').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).siblings('.group-dealer').toggle();
    });

});
```

There will be more nodes that will be positioned differently so the full class name I provided is necessary.  The markup (generally speaking) is as follows:

```
<div class="node-202">
    <div class="group-dealer">...</div>
    <div class="field-name-field-pin-point">...</div>
</div>
```

I am basically creating points on a map that when clicked, bring up a small window with more information about that location.

Here is a reference to my last post if you are looking for more information: [Toggle Class Visibility by Clicking on another Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501210/toggle-class-visibility-by-clicking-on-another-class)

Comment: "none" isn't a valid value for the visibility property. You'd want "hidden". That said, I'm not clear on your question. Why can't you just change the styles for `.group-dealer`?

Comment: you want `visibility:hidden` Also you can make another function (say `toggleVisibility(obj)`) where `obj` is a jQuery object, and then the function body would be something like `obj.css({"visibility":"hidden"})` (along with logic to switch to `visible` when applicable) Then call `toggleVisibility(obj)` instead of `obj.toggle()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest your best approach is to add a css rule and just toggle a class on the elements

CSS

```
.group-dealer.hidden{ visibility:hidden}
```

JS

```
jQuery('.node-202 .field-name-field-pin-point').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).siblings('.group-dealer').addClass('hidden');/* use toggleClass if more appropriate*/
})
```

Comment: ya, adding/removing a class and let CSS handles the design part +1

Comment: This works! I added the css as well.  Thank you.  I changed it to toggleClass to test, and on page load it does the inverse of what I want (the pop up shows right away) but the function works.  I probably just have to play with the css or change is back to addClass.

Comment: usually simplest to look at using css classes first...is easier to undo , especially if changing multiple display properties

Answer (score 0):

Just toggle the visibility then

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.node-202 .field-name-field-pin-point').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).siblings('.group-dealer').css('visibility', function(_,vis) {
            return vis == 'hidden' ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I just replaced this line:

        jQuery(this).siblings('.group-dealer').toggle();
        });

with what you stated, but it did not work.

Comment: That's probably because that line also contains the closing of the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.node-202 .field-name-field-pin-point').click(function () {
    if ($(this).siblings().css('visibility') == 'visible') {
        $(this).siblings().css('visibility', 'hidden');
    } else {
        $(this).siblings().css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4WXc/1)

Comment: several problems `is` will be true if any of the elements pass condition, and `:visible` selector will be true all the time also when `visibility` is used. See [:visible selector docs](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Comment: you should fix your code, there are many errors in this answer

Comment: @Hiral I tried your updated answer from right when you posted your comment, but still no success.