# How to make content within div to disappear without content space closing up? -- jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am messing around with a small div containing three p's. If the user clicks any of the p's they all disappear.  There is a small button to readd the content.  I'm looking for a way to remove the content without the div closing up.

Below is that I have.

```
<script>
    $(function () 
    {
        $("p, button").click(function () 
        {
           $("p").toggle();
        })
    });
</script>
<div id="blarg" class="blarg" style="visibility: visible;">
    <p class="test" style="display: block;">If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
    <p class="test" style="display: block;">Click me away!</p>
    <p class="test" style="display: block;">Click me too!</p>
</div>
<button>Readd</button>
```

Comment: You can find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614622/equivalent-of-jquery-hide-to-set-visibility-hidden

Comment: So clicking a paragraph should remove only that paragraph, but what should clicking the button do?

Comment: Clicking any of the p's should remove them all.  Originally, I was testing to see if toggle would remove the content without removing the content space.  I left the button there to put the content back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css style `visiblity` can do this for you. You just need to set it to `visibility:hidden` like this:

```
$(function () 
{
     $("p, button").click(function () 
     {
         $(this).css("visibility","hidden");
     })

});
```

Comment: By the same token you mentioned earlier... you are applying the style to all `p`

Comment: Woops. Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle is using "display", wich makes the item occupy space, I think you want to use `visibility`, wich does not affect layout, just it... visibility.

Answer (score -1):

Set `visibility: hidden;` on each of the `p` elements on click.

```
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

$("p, button").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

EDIT: Good catch guys... wrote that too fast.

Comment: you can just do `$(this).toggleClass('hidden')` instead of an if-else

Comment: This will make **all** of them disappear with one click. I think what you want to use inside of the `function` is `$(this)`

Comment: @SimchaKhabinsky is right. Change `$('p')` to `$(this)`