# .show() not working on page load - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to get the jQuery to animate the loading of my page. I have proved that jQuery is working correctly because  it works with .hide();

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dAFvU/1/)

Here is my JavaScript File

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".intro").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

`display: none;`

instead of

`visibility: hidden;`

for the class `.intro` in your css.

Here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dAFvU/5/).

Comment: Ok, sorry I just started with jQuery

Comment: @thomfur : actually its a CSS thing. `visibility` and `display` properties have different use cases.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have this is your CSS:

```
.intro {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

To fix this, change your CSS to:

```
.intro {
    display: none;
}
```

**OR**

Change the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".intro").css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

The jQuery [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) method sets the style of an element to `display: block;` but ignores the `visibility` style. The [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method essentially adds `display: none;` to an element.

[Here is a good related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614622/equivalent-of-jquery-hide-to-set-visibility-hidden).

Answer (score 0):

In your css, you are setting `visibility: hidden;`. Change it to `display:none`.

Because `.show()` is basically doing `display:block`.

OR

Change the code like this `$(".intro").css("visibility","visible")`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dAFvU/6/)