# How to preserve position of a column, when hiding the previous one?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a row with three columns and a button. When I click on a button, the second column hides and the third one takes it place. How can I force the third column to remain on the same position where it was before hiding the second one? Here is my code:

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
   Column 1
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 test">
   Column 2
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
   Column 3
  </div>
 </div>
<button id="btn">
 Hide column 3
</button>

$('#btn').click(function(){
 $('.test').hide();
});
```

Comment: Instead of hide, change visibility, this will hide but preserve the space it takes up - google css visibility for more details - have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614622/equivalent-of-jquery-hide-to-set-visibility-hidden

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `hide` use

```
 $('.test').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

you can also use `.css('opacity', '0')`