# How do I hide an html element on a specific page that already has the style (visibility: visible) and only if the child has a certain class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, learndash

I have content/posts that are shown in a grid on one webpage from which a user can choose and subsequently be taken to that specific content on another page. I have the same grid of content/posts on six different pages. On each page I want to filter out content based on a specific class.

Each item in the grid is already styled "visible" I suspect by the plugin I'm using.

In the example below, the class I want to use to filter the content is  "ld_topic_category-video-interaction-a1". The element I want to hide is the specific "item grid-1" which is connected to "ld_topic_category-video-interaction-a1".

```
<div class="item grid-1" style="visibility: visible;">
    <article id="post-2637" class="post post-2637 sfwd-topic type-sfwd-topic status-publish hentry ld_topic_category-video-interaction-a1 user-has-not-earned"...</article>
</div>
```

I've tried the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('ld_topic_category-video-interaction-a1').each(function(){
       if($(this).hasClass("ld_topic_category-video-interaction-a1")){
        $(this).parent().css("display", "none");
       }
});
});
```

As well as:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('ld_topic_category-video-interaction-a1').each(function(){
       if($(this).hasClass("ld_topic_category-video-interaction-a1")){
        $(this).parent().hide();
       }
});
});
```

And this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ld_topic_category-video-interaction-a1');

for(let i=0; i< elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Also this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.item.grid-1').each(function(){
       if($(this).hasClass("ld_topic_category-video-interaction-a1")){
        $(this).parent().css("display", "none");
       }
});
});
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if there is any other info I need to provide.

Thanks

Comment: `$(this).parent().css("visibility","hidden");` - Try changing the visibility

Answer (score 0):

CSS Visibility and Display properties are not the same. Please refer to the link below:
[https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-visibility.php#:~:text=CSS%20Visibility%20vs,affect%20the%20layouts](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-visibility.php#:%7E:text=CSS%20Visibility%20vs,affect%20the%20layouts).

If you want to stick with visibility style you can do this instead to hide the element:

```
$(this).parent().css("visibility", "visible"); //this is to make element visible again 
$(this).parent().css("visibility", "hidden"); //this is to make element hidden
```

Refer to this answer for more info on CSS Visibility:
[Equivalent of jQuery .hide() to set visibility: hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614622/equivalent-of-jquery-hide-to-set-visibility-hidden)

If you wanna stick with your jquery code however, you can instead make do with  Display property:

```
<div class="item grid-1" style="display:block;"> //to show the element
     <article id="post-2637" class="post post-2637 sfwd-topic type-sfwd-topic status-publish hentry ld_topic_category-video-interaction-a1 user-has-not-earned"... 
     </article>
</div>

<div class="item grid-1" style="display:none;"> //to hide the element
     <article id="post-2637" class="post post-2637 sfwd-topic type-sfwd-topic status-publish hentry ld_topic_category-video-interaction-a1 user-has-not-earned"... 
     </article>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

could you use display: none to hide the items of the grid you don't want?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).